# Password Protecting External EXE Files?

Tags: c#

I have a question about programs that password EXE files on the users PC.
I actually wanted to know how these work, the ones that allow the passworded EXE to run on a PC without the software installed.

Do they add something in the program, or do they somehow replace it with a program that runs the exe in memory?

Now, I wanted to know how this could be done in C#, is it even possible?
I would like to be able to create authentication of my own for the programs on my computer(I assume some would be in C++, some in DotNet and what ever other languages popular games/programs are created with).

Thanks to anyone who can answer/help me :)

Comment: I mean things like this: http://www.windowscleanuptool.com/exepassword/free_exe_password.htm

Comment: @CokaCola: it's really not clear, may be give some example or link were you see that stuff, could help to understand what you mean

Comment: @CokaCola: why do not just use  the tool you pointed out? It's also free...

Comment: I want to be able to create my own methods, also I wanted to know how they actually work

Answer (score 0):

A way I have found very good is a HWID protection where you have an database online with allowed HWID's then it checks if your HWID is allowed to run this program

Comment: This is a terrible idea. When your app gets cracked, legitimate users will get hosed if either they don't have Internet or your server goes down, while pirates will have a working program. See: http://kotaku.com/5487918/ubisofts-new-drm-system-falls-down-locks-out-paying-customers